# Получить данные из строки

Tags: php

```
$str = 'Thu, 10 Dec 2020 17:00:00 +0600'
```

Как получить из строки `17:00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'Thu, 10 Dec 2020 17:00:00 +0600';

preg_match('/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];

// либо 

$date = date_parse($str);
echo sprintf("%02d", $date['hour']) . ':' . sprintf("%02d", $date['minute']) . ':' . sprintf("%02d", $date['second']);
```